# MS Access multiple default values for one field

Tags: ms-access

Building an ms access data base. I have one field called `form type`.

I have 4 forms pulling from this field. Currently I have a drop down stating `Internal`, `External`, `Other`, and `Cases`.

My co-workers select the wrong drop down item for the form they are using.

Is there a way to have multiple default values for a single field?

Or can the field be auto filled when submitted without the user selecting anything?

I tried no default value with a data validation drop down list. I have searched the web for alternative methods with no avail.

My expected result would include the form auto selecting the correct "Form Type" for the field. This way there is no user error.

Thanks for taking a look, Matt

Comment: What would be the rules for any automatism to choose the correct value in the combo box?

Comment: Form Type = Combo Box                                                                       If the form Name is External Transfer then the from type combo box should default to "External", if the form name is Internal Transfer then the form type should be "Internal", if the Form Name is BnF then the form type should be BnF, if the form name is Business Cases then the Form Type should be Business Cases.

Comment: To be clear: You have 4 different forms using the same table-field. So why not put a different default value in each form for this control?

Comment: You are correct. 4 forms using the same field.  I didn't think it was possible. I haven't been able to find anything on it. Do you know where to go for this? Thank you!

Comment: In the `design view` of each form select the combo box and then if not already, open the `Property Sheet` (e.g. `F4`). Then put the proper default value in the property `Default Value`.

Comment: Worked Like a charm. Can't believe I search for 3 hours and it was this easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have four different forms using the same table-field, you can put a different default value in each form for this control:

In the design view of each form select the combo box and then, if not already done, open the `Property Sheet` (e.g. with key `F4`).

Then put the proper default value in the property `Default Value` and you're done.